# my nodejs server exits on the event loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function

```
function flashSetup (_super, settings) {
var server = createServer(_super, settings);

/**
 * Set event listeners for each server
 */

// On each connection
server.on("connection", server.connectionListener);

// On each request
server.on('request', server.requestListener);

console.log("server listening @ port " + server.port);

return server;
}
```

and its called in a forEach loop like this:

```
 array.forEach(flashSetup);
```

The problem is, this comes out:

```
 server listening @ port 8080
```

and node exits. can someone help, why node is terminating abruptly?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a server.listen() call.

Comment: what a facepalm moment! Thanks!